# Number of comments shown on load has increased on Meta

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, comments

In the intervening months since the [feature was introduced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-top-n-shown/), there have always been at most 5 comments shown under a post when the page loads. However, it seems that, on Meta, that limit has been tripled.

There doesn't yet seem to be a user preference to tweak this number, so I think that this is likely a bug somewhere.

As an example, check out [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/how-to-deal-with-unwritten-rules-and-guidelines-on-stackoverflow-et-al/3180#3180). Instead of showing 5, now 15 comments are displayed under the post, taking up significant space:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Jeff's answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396/a-little-less-ajax).

He's just upped the displayed comments from 5 to 15.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. I guess this is one of those changes you don't notice right away. Still, I think it would be best to leave this up to the user, as was originally promised.

Comment: Lame, I don't want to be forced to scroll through 15 comments on large discussion pages.

Comment: Don't blame me - I'm just the messenger ;)